# sending email from wcf web service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, email

I have a WCF web service. I want to send email from this service. There are libraries for sending email from WCF?
I want that library have simple scheduler, for example, send every hour or something like that. Can't find anything.

Comment: -1. SO is not search engine, especially if code you are looking for is part of the Framework.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  I need to advice, exprerience of other people. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET's [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) works fine from a WCF web service.

You can use [Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) to schedule sending of emails.